# How to get annotations of a variable in external method using Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, annotations, kotlin-reflect

I'm starting with Kotlin reflection. I need to write a method in Kotlin that would take a variable (in this case lets say of type String) and return all annotations (if any) that are applied to that variable.

```
fun getAnnotations(variable: String): List<Annotation>{
   //get annotations here
}
```

Of course that is only possible if annotations are also passed to the method along with variable itself. I wasn't able to find that info in documentation. For my use case, it is not acceptable to send entire user object to getAnnotations method. So I can't use `User::class.getDeclaredField`. I need a method that can extract annotations from variable.

Looking forward to learning.
Thanks

Example:

Class and annotation:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
annotation class MyAnnotation()


data class User(

   @MyAnnotation
   val name: String,

   val address: String
   ...
)
```

Usage:

```
//user data is fetched and stored in 'user' object
println(getAnnotations(user.name))      //should return @MyAnnotation
println(getAnnotations(user.address))   //should return empty list
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value passed around doesn't hold references to annotations because the annotations are not on the value but on something else, on some "static" definition like a class, a property, a file, etc.

In your case, the annotation is on the property. When you call `user.name`, you get the value that the property is currently pointing to, not the property itself. If you want to extract the annotation from the property you need a reference to it, which you can get by using `::`. To get the annotations on the `name` property in the `User` class, you can call:

```kotlin
User::name.annotations
```

Comment: Thank you, this clears a lot.